# React Router v6 - not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React. I cannot understand why react router v6 is not rendering any component.

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Customers, Invoices, Jobs, Login, Sales, } from './modules'

import './App.css';
import './index.css';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
                <Route path="/jobs" element={<Jobs />} />
                <Route path="customers" element={<Customers />} />
                <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
                <Route path="sales" element={<Sales />} />
                <Route
                path="*"
                element={
                    <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
                    <p>There's nothing here!</p>
                    </main>
                }
                />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    rootElement
);
```

**src/modules/invoices/Invoices.js**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { getInvoices } from "../../data";

export default function Invoices() {
  let invoices = getInvoices();
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <nav
        style={{
          borderRight: "solid 1px",
          padding: "1rem",
        }}
      >
        {invoices.map((invoice) => (
          <Link
            style={{ display: "block", margin: "1rem 0" }}
            to={`/invoices/${invoice.number}`}
            key={invoice.number}
          >
            {invoice.name}
          </Link>
        ))}
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the data.js is taken from react-router docs https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How about `invoices` vs `/invoices` in your route?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong, are there any errors/warnings in the console?

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all? your imports are messed up. It needs to be `import Invoices from './modules/invoices/Invoices'`

Comment: @Art no errors. Import are fine. In ./modules I have Index.js file with exports like

`export { default as Invoices } from './invoices/Invoices';`

Comment: Could your add App component here? It needs to have an Outlet, and if your imports are fine and everything else seems to be good, that must be the issue

Answer (score -1):

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />}/>
            <Route path="/jobs" element={<Jobs />} />
            <Route path="/customers" element={<Customers />} />
            <Route path="/invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
            <Route path="/sales" element={<Sales />} />
            <Route
                path="*"
                element={
                    <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
                    <p>There's nothing here!</p>
                    </main>
                }
            />
       
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    rootElement
);
```

I found these mistakes ,

1. you have included all the components inside a single Route.

or if you want everything to be inside your  component.
Then initialise the routers in the App component itself.
You can refer this https://github.com/NaveenkumarMD/cryptera-website/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: According to documentation, it's a nested route: [https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes)

Answer (score -1):

needs to be added in the  component. I hope app component will b rendered, we have to mention the place holder where we have to render the child component.

Comment: To be considered a more helpful answer, can you please provide an example of the code to complete what you're saying?